# MapStruct: Mapping 2 objects to a 3rd one

Tags: java, object-object-mapping, mapstruct

I have Object1 and Object2. Now, I want to map object3, with attributes from 1 & 2.

Say, I have 2 object:

```
1. User: {first_name, last_name, id}
2. Address: {street, locality, city, state, pin, id}
```

Now, with these, I want to map that in

```
User_View: {firstName, lastName, city, state}.
```

Where, first_name & last_name will be from User object 
and city & state from Address object.

**Now, my question is, how to do that?**

However, currently, I'm doing like this

```
@Mapper    
public abstract class UserViewMapper {
        @Mappings({
                    @Mapping(source = "first_name", target = "firstName"),
                    @Mapping(source = "last_name", target = "lastName"),
                    @Mapping(target = "city", ignore = true),
                    @Mapping(target = "state", ignore = true)

            })
            public abstract UserView userToView(User user);

        public UserView addressToView(UserView userView, Address address) {

                if (userView == null) {
                    return null;
                }

                if (address == null) {
                    return null;
                }

                userView.setCity(address.getCity());
                userView.setState(address.getState()); 

            return userView;

            }
    }
```

But, here, I have to manually write the mapping in `addressToView()`.

**Therefore, is there, any way, to avoid that?**

**Or, what would be the preferred way, to handle such situations?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can declare a mapping method with several source parameters and refer to the properties of all these parameters in your `@Mapping` annotations:

```
@Mapper
public abstract class UserViewMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "first_name", target = "user.firstName"),
    @Mapping(source = "last_name", target = "user.lastName"),
    public abstract UserView userAndAddressToView(User user, Address address);
}
```

As the "city" and "state" property names match in source and target, there is no need for mapping them.

Also see the chapter ["Defining a mapper"](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#defining-mapper) in the reference documentation for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. one question, what, if i have same attribute in both the input objects, that means, what if, User & Address, both have an attribute with same name, which one, will be mapped, or how i will define the source for that?

Comment: I think you are mixing up source and target in your answer. It should be: 
`@Mapping(source = "user.first_name", target = "firstName")`

Answer (score 1):

Using MapStruct you are missing a step using the @Mapper annotation.  The @Mapper will create the implementation of the mappings.

You should review the docs at this link http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/

Specifically

> 3. Defining a mapper
>
> In this section you’ll learn how to define a bean mapper with
>   MapStruct and which options you have to do so.
>   3.1 Basic mappings
>
> To create a mapper simply define a Java interface with the required
>   mapping method(s) and annotate it with the org.mapstruct.Mapper
>   annotation:
>
> ```
> @Mapper
> public interface CarMapper {
>
>     @Mappings({
>         @Mapping(source = "make", target = "manufacturer"),
>         @Mapping(source = "numberOfSeats", target = "seatCount")
>     })
>     CarDto carToCarDto(Car car);
>
>     @Mapping(source = "name", target = "fullName")
>     PersonDto personToPersonDto(Person person);
> }
> ```
>
> The @Mapper annotation causes the MapStruct code generator to create
>   an implementation of the CarMapper interface during build-time.

Comment: If [Java8, @Mappings not necessary](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/dev/api/org/mapstruct/Mappings.html):  "When using Java 8 or later, you can omit the @ Mappings wrapper annotation and directly specify several @ Mapping annotations on one method."