# Configure ModelMapper to map nested object to field

Tags: java, modelmapper

Here are my DTOs:

```
public class TagVolumeDTO {
    private Long id;
    private Long idTag;
    //...
}

public class TagTDO {
    private Long id;
    private Long amount;
    //...
}
```

and here are my entities:

```
public class TagVolume {
    private Long id;
    private Tag tag;
    //...
}

public class Tag {
    private Long id;
    private Long amount;
    //...
}
```

I would like to configure my ModelMapper to map Tag#id to TagVolumeDTO#idTag.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 5):

Configuration:

```
ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
mapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);
mapper.typeMap(TagVolume.class, TagVolumeDTO.class)
        .addMappings(m -> m.map(src -> src.getTag().getId(), TagVolumeDTO::setIdTag));
```

Usage:

```
Tag tag = new Tag();
tag.setId(1L);
tag.setAmount(10L);
TagVolume tagVolume = new TagVolume();
tagVolume.setId(123L);
tagVolume.setTag(tag);
System.out.println(mapper.map(tagVolume.getTag(), TagDTO.class));
System.out.println(mapper.map(tagVolume, TagVolumeDTO.class));
```

Output:

> TagDTO(id=1, amount=10)
>
> TagVolumeDTO(id=123, idTag=1)

ModelMapper version: **1.1.0**

P.s. You can to organize your code similar to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47929674/modelmapper-mapping-list-of-entites-to-list-of-dto-objects) in another question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this does not work: The destination property TagVolumeDTO.setIdTag() matches multiple source property hierarchies

Comment: @Florent06 you want to map Tag to TagVolumeDTO, right?

Comment: I want to map Tag to TagDTO and TagVolume to TagVolumeDTO. But, as you can see in my 1st post, TagVolume as a field referenced as a Tag. But, in my DTOs, TagVolumeDTO has no reference to TagVolume. Only the Tag's id.

Comment: @Florent06, What is the match strategy of your model mapper?

Comment: I have not set any match strategy.

Comment: clear and perfect answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For these kind of mapping it is preferred to used AnnotationProcessor like mapStuct which reduces code.

> It will generate code for Mapper

```
  @Mapper
public interface SimpleSourceDestinationMapper {
    TagVolumeDTO sourceToDestination(Tag source);
    Tag destinationToSource(TagVolumeDTO destination);
}
```

> usage of these mapper is as follow

```
private SimpleSourceDestinationMapper mapper
      = Mappers.getMapper(SimpleSourceDestinationMapper.class);

TagVolumeDTO destination = mapper.sourceToDestination(tag);
```

Kindly find link for detailed implementation 
[MapStuct](http://www.baeldung.com/mapstruct)

Comment: This is not what I want. If you take a look at my objects, you'll see 2 DTOs and 2 entities. One of the entities has a field of type of the second.

Comment: What you are saying is also possible with MapStruct see this stack overflow link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130599/mapstruct-mapping-2-objects-to-a-3rd-one

Comment: Thank you but I think this solution is a bit too hard to set up. Though, I can not set up it with my Junit Tests.