# ModelMapper, mapping list of Entites to List of DTO objects

Tags: java, modelmapper

I am writing simple blog web application using Spring MVC framework. I am willing to add `DTO` layer to my app.

I decided to use [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/) framework for conversion from `Entity` objects to `DTO` objects used in my views.

I have just one problem.
On my main page, I am showing a list of posts on my blog. In my view, it's just list of `Post` (Entity) objects. I want to change it to pass a list of `PostDTO` objects to my view. Is there any way to map `List` of `Post` objects to `List` of `PostDTO` object with single method call?
I was thinking about writing [converter](http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/converters/) that will convert this but I am not sure it's a good way to do it.

Also, I am using `Lists` of `Entities` in few more places like administrative panel or comment below every Post on my page.

Link to code of my app on GitHub repository: [repository](https://github.com/Gromo13/personalBlog/tree/dto)

Comment: If you have lazy relation to initialize, use `@transactional` or follow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42643297/13459296) to another answer.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can create util class:

```
public class ObjectMapperUtils {

    private static final ModelMapper modelMapper;

    /**
     * Model mapper property setting are specified in the following block.
     * Default property matching strategy is set to Strict see {@link MatchingStrategies}
     * Custom mappings are added using {@link ModelMapper#addMappings(PropertyMap)}
     */
    static {
        modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);
    }

    /**
     * Hide from public usage.
     */
    private ObjectMapperUtils() {
    }

    /**
     * <p>Note: outClass object must have default constructor with no arguments</p>
     *
     * @param <D>      type of result object.
     * @param <T>      type of source object to map from.
     * @param entity   entity that needs to be mapped.
     * @param outClass class of result object.
     * @return new object of <code>outClass</code> type.
     */
    public static <D, T> D map(final T entity, Class<D> outClass) {
        return modelMapper.map(entity, outClass);
    }

    /**
     * <p>Note: outClass object must have default constructor with no arguments</p>
     *
     * @param entityList list of entities that needs to be mapped
     * @param outCLass   class of result list element
     * @param <D>        type of objects in result list
     * @param <T>        type of entity in <code>entityList</code>
     * @return list of mapped object with <code><D></code> type.
     */
    public static <D, T> List<D> mapAll(final Collection<T> entityList, Class<D> outCLass) {
        return entityList.stream()
                .map(entity -> map(entity, outCLass))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    /**
     * Maps {@code source} to {@code destination}.
     *
     * @param source      object to map from
     * @param destination object to map to
     */
    public static <S, D> D map(final S source, D destination) {
        modelMapper.map(source, destination);
        return destination;
    }
}
```

And use it for your needs:

```
List<PostDTO> listOfPostDTO = ObjectMapperUtils.mapAll(listOfPosts, PostDTO.class);
```

Comment: Based on your code I wrote something similar, but easier to understand for me. And most importand, "mine". I am generally new to `Generics` in `Java`. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I have a question, now how can we handle the custom mapping with this generics class. I need to map 2 very different objects which I can't do as it is with this class and I really liked the approach you are following! Thnx.

Comment: @ajkush, take a look at modelmapper typemaps.

Comment: Thank you @AndrewNepogoda ! Created a custom converter and added it to the mapper in ObjectMappingUtils.

Comment: Thank's so much! Important solution for many situations!

Comment: Great answer, but How can I ignore the field in the DTO, which don't need to map from Entity?

Comment: @AndrewNepogoda What is the benfit of using stream over using the "Type" and "TypeToken" to directly map the said lists using the modelmapper?

Comment: @DrishtiJain, I think there're no benefits. You can use both. "Type" and "TypeToken" looks even nicer. I voted this answer as well.

Comment: @Hungnn, you can use type maps and skip properties like: `typeMap.addMappings(mapper -> mapper.skip(Destination::setName));`

Answer (score 40):

considering you have a list of Post Entity (`postEntityList`) and a PostDTO class, you can try following:

use the following imports to get the desired results

```
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;
import org.modelmapper.TypeToken;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
```

use the below code

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<PostDTO>>(){}.getType();
List<PostDTO> postDtoList = modelmapper.map(postEntityList,listType);
```

Comment: should be modelmapper.map

Answer (score 20):

Try the following simple way:

```
List<PostDTO> postDtoList = Arrays.asList(modelMapper.map(postEntityList, PostDTO[].class));
```

Comment: Why is util class being used as solution when this is clearly easier and out of the box without the need of custom code that does the same?

Answer (score 16):

since you want to convert Entity to Dto, you can try the following one

```
List<PostDTO> entityToDto = modelMapper.map(postEntity, new TypeToken<List<PostDTO>>(){}.getType());
```

Comment: This seems like the most straightforward approach

Answer (score 5):

Let's assume you are reading from the database, and want to convert from entities in the DB to DTOs

The service layer might be separated from the controller (always the best approach), then do this:

Service layer code:

```
@Override
    public List<PostDTO> convertEntityToDTOList( ){
            List<Post> post = postRepository.findAll();
            Type listType = new TypeToken<List<PostDTO>>(){}.getType();
            List<PostDTO> postDTOList = modelMapper.map(post, listType);
            return postDTOList;
        }
```

Then in your controller, add this:

```
public ResponseEntity<?> list(){
        List<PostDTO> postDTOList = iPost.convertEntityToDTOList();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(postDTOList, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Note that the iPost is an interface that defines method.
This is it:

```
public interface iPost {
   List<PostDTO> convertEntityToDTOList();
}
```

Credits to @André Carvalho